# Not able to access Zomato developers page

Tags: node.js, api, zomato-api

I want to request for Zomato API key. However, their developers page https://developers.zomato.com/api is showing 404 error.
The URL is taken from npm page for Zomato API https://www.npmjs.com/package/zomato-api .
I've watched few youtube videos which work with Zomato API, the required web page was getting displayed earlier.
Has Zomato stopped providing API or there is a new way to access it? Please help.

Comment: have you figured out any conclusion? Is zomato dev access shut now?

Comment: I am totally confused by this as well because the API key I previously generated is still working.

Comment: Im not able to open their developer page as well

Answer (score 4):

https://twitter.com/zomatocare/status/1391288230818029571?s=21

Yes they have stopped api support :(

Comment: Then how does the petpooja handling zomato and swiggi online orders on their app

Answer (score 0):

I had my old account I tried using it and my react native app went mad
It gave 500 error but later I found API was shutdown

Answer (score 0):

I have made an unofficial zomato API (merchant)

see : https://github.com/ripyas/zomato-api

Nb: do't care about pricing.